# Colour of the letters in contacts?

Tags: contacts, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, google-contacts

What is the meaning ot the different colours of the letters in android contacts?

I use Nexus4 with standard 4.4

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nothing Special. Multiple color for single Letter is to differentiate multiple contacts starting with similar letter.